# How to open a .py in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to learn how to use Python (IDLE using Python 3.4) on my Ubuntu computer, but i dont know how to open/run a .py file from the terminal from the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Save your program with .py extension

For example:  hello.py

Open Terminal.., change directory to location where that program is located.

type

> python3 ./File_name.py

For example:  python3 ./hello.py

Refer [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Creating_Python_Programs)

Comment: Please drop by the [AU general chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and @Fabby me there for your other questions...